# Hölder continuity of process from Donsker like theorem with Cauchy random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $X_k$ be i.i.d. Cauchy random variables with parameters $0,1$. For each $N$ define the process $Y_N$ by $$Y_N(t)=\frac{1}N\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor tN\rfloor}X_k+\text{piecewise linear interpolation}.$$

Note that for each grid point, the sum of Cauchy random variables is another Cauchy random variable. I am interested in the convergence of this process. Is the limit continuous? Is it Hölder? We cannot apply Kolmogorov continuity criterion due to lack of moments.

Comment: For a given integer $n$, how does one tell whether $X_n$ means $X_k$ with $k = n$ or $X_N$ with $N = n$?

Comment: @LSpice Fixed..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed this falls a bit outside of the standard theory. As mentioned in this MSE answer to [Does a random walk with infinite mean ever converge to anything?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577043/does-a-random-walk-with-infinite-mean-ever-converge-to-anything), in particular for Cauchy too in the second answer, one has to use the stable FCLT to get  that the limit of this random walk is the [Cauchy process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_process). For example, as mentioned in the comments from these notes ["Stochastic-process limits"](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eww2040/jumps.html) by Whitt, we can use theorem 4.5.3.

Comment: You refer to "this MSE answer", but your link was to the question, and I edited accordingly.  You refer to "the second answer", so I assume you meant "the first answer" the first time, but the order of answers can change over time, and according to a user's preferred sorting.  Which answer do you mean when?